# How to fix unusual initial DEM input values and derivative raster output values in SAGA GIS without rescaling?

Tags: dem, geoprocessing, saga, tools, topography

I am trying to run elevation derivative tools on a provincial DEM provided by the Ontario Government website (Ministry of Natural Resources and Forestry) and I am getting strange values when bringing the data into SAGA GIS.

The values show up like normal in ArcMap but I get an unusually extremely low minimum value (that should be 0) as displayed in the image below:

[image]

As displayed, I am currently trying to create a Topographic Position Index (TPI) and the output values are also unusually large. Only when I adjust the min/max values can I get a proper visualization in the display windows, but the metadata in the "Description" tab does not change. On top of that, when I save the SAGA file and bring it into ArcMap I get more strange values. Only when I rescale using the "Rescale by function" (linear transformation function) tool in ArcMap can I get a normal visualization in ArcMap, similar to when I changed the raster's min/max values in SAGA and even then I am unsure if I input the parameters correctly into the ArcMap tool.

Would anyone also know what a typical standard TPI Index value range should be? And would anyone know the proper parameter inputs for a linear transformation function via the "Rescale by function" tool in ArcMap?

Comment: The Min. -3400000...... value in your first image looks suspiciously close to the listed noData value.  Are noData values getting mixed into your statistics causing issues?

Answer (score 2):

It seems SAGA has an issue with its Import Raster function to read GeoTiff tags. The strange NoData value (-3.40282e+038) is probably (-32767) in the original dataset.

As already pointed out by @Rex, this strange value was used by TPI tool as a part of the surface and seriously damaged the result.

Please modify NoData value of the imported grid to -99999, which TPI tool can correctly recognize. 
You can use `Reclassify Grid Values` tool under the  menu `Geoprocessing | Grid | Values |`.

`Reclassify Grid Values` tool offers various options, but you only need to work on `Special cases`by

- Tick on the `no data values` and put `-99999` in the `new value`
- NoData Output Grid `Assign... user defined NoData value` and give `-99999`.

This will return a reclassified grid with `_reclassifed` suffix. Re-run TPI on the new grid.

Comment: What do you mean re-run the TPI on the new grid? I can't run the TPI on an already-processed TPI raster since there's no raw elevation data. And I'm pretty sure -99999 is already set as NoData without running that tool so it didn't do anything.

Comment: @ATomz "Re-run" does not mean to run TPI twice, but my apologies if the word is misleading. It should read "Run TPI on the new grid" then.