# Calculate TPI for irregular DEM

Tags: qgis, dem, saga, tpi

When I use SAGA's Tool Topographic Position Index (TPI) or Tool TPI Based Landform Classification (in QGIS or SAGA itself) on a rectangular DEM the results are as expected but when I try them on a DEM with irregular borders I get the following result:
[image: Result of TPI on irregular DEM]

Is it possible to calculate TPI on this kind of DEM or do I need to subset it on multiple rectangular tiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another [Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237680/how-to-fix-unusual-initial-dem-input-values-and-derivative-raster-output-values?rq=1) which gave me a hint on what the problem could be. SAGA recognize No Data values as -99999. Other values get processed as regular.
I solved my problem reclassifying No Data values (which were being read as -3.4e+38) as -99999.